# Website on EC2 running slow sometimes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a PHP website on an Amazon EC2 instance. Sometimes the website runs slow.

Here are the metrics:

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-cpu-credits

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look into the log files to see what kind of traffic is being generated - assuming that this is traffic related. This could be caused by hackers trolling your website.

This could also be caused by having too small of an EC2 instance for the traffic that your site receives.

You will need to look into the details in log files, etc. to discover what the real cause is.